# How to retrieve class element from a haml document

Tags: class, dom, haml

I am trying to access the DOM element for 'show more topics' from the haml file

```
#profile-wrapper.container-fluid
  .sidebar
    .profile
    %h4 Interests
    %ul.topics
    %a.show_more_topics.hide Show More
```

I tried to run the following code:

```
$('.topics .show_more_topics')
```

However I am getting back an empty array [].

How can I retrieve the 'show more topics' element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link with class `show_more_topics` is a *sibling* of the `topics` list (see how they're indented the same?), while the selector `.topics .show_more_topics` selects an element with the class `show_more_topics` that's a *descendent* of an element with the class `topics`.

You just want `$('.show_more_topics')`.